# Куда отправляется содержимое буфера вывода?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Куда отправляется содержимое буфера вывода `ob_flush()`? В браузер в данном случае?
**Если в конце кода не ставить `ob_flush();`, строка все равно выводится. Или php ставит его самостоятельно?..**

```
ob_start();                // включить буфер
echo 'Test';               // это echo попадает в буфер (задерживается)
setcookie("name", "John"); // установить (отправить) куки

echo $_COOKIE['name'];     // => John

ob_flush();                // Сброс (отправка) буфера вывода
```

Comment: в обычной жизни эти функции обычно не используется. Содержимое буфера передается http-серверу, который добавляет его к ответу и пересылает клиенту. При обычном выполнении скрипта после его выполнения сервер так же отправляет результат. Полезность использования буфера в том, что его можно очистить, и не оправлять уже выведенные данные.

Comment: Буфер используется для того, чтобы упростить код. Вы можете вывести шапку страницы и лишь потом приступить к обработке параметров. Если в результате вы захотите сделать редирект, то не сможете этого сделать, поскольку редирект делается через заголовок HTTP-ответа, а у вас уже выведена часть содержимого. Чтобы эту ситуацию обойти, и применяется буфер. Весь вывод складывается в область памяти, а в конце скрипта, если всё нормально, её содержимое выводится в поток вывода, то есть, по факту, передаётся HTTP-клиенту.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: @АлександрЖариченко дабы понимать, почему я отредактировал ваш пост и в т.ч. убрал оттуда _"здравствуйте"_, которое вы вернули, ознакомьтесь [этим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/95/223826)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Буфер принудительно сбрасывается по окончанию запроса, если ранее не была вызвана функция `ob_flush` или аналоги. Предотвратить вывод можно путем использования соответствующих функций (например `ob_end_clean`)